# How to cut a hole with a specific shape into a plane?

Tags: modeling

I need to cut a hole through the plane behind the tunnel. What is the best way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the boolean modifier?

Comment: or knife tool: Knife project

Comment: yes, knife project too , the bool tool also works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways you can make an object intersect into another object, some examples are bool tool, boolean modifier or the knife project like chris mentioned in one of the comments. But I commonly use the bool tool because I personally think that the bool tool is way more easier than the rest.The bool tool and the Boolean modifier are similar to each other. The difference is that the bool tool is an add-on and the Boolean is a modifier.

**1. Bool Tool**

[image]

Just go edit> prefernces> addons, search 'Bool tool' and enable the free addon.

[image]

Now first select ' the object that you want to be cut on another object ' and then select the second ' object in which you want another object to be cut on'  [tried my best to make simple as I could :) ]. Then press 'N', go to the edit tab and open up the 'Bool tool' dropdown and then finally press 'Difference'.

**2. Boolean modifier**

[image]

First, select the object in which you want another object to be cut on, go to the modifiers tab, select the boolean modifier, in the boolean setting select your object by either typing its name or selecting it with the eyedropper in the 'object'

**NOTE:**
If you want the cut to be permanent on the object just select the Boolean modifier and press 'Ctrl + A' to apply it. (steps **aren't** included in the GIF)